# List all the files included in a python package (equivalent to 'git ls-files')

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am having issues with installing my python package because some of the unintended files and folders are most probably included in my package. I have excluded many files and folders using `MANIFEST.in` as well as `exclude=` option inside the `setup.py` file. However, it seems almost impossible to rectify the issue without knowing the list of all the files/folders that are "tracked" in my package.

There is a neat system in git-based version-control system, that allows ignoring files/folders from a single file `.gitignore` and listing files that are included in the repository using `git ls-files` command.

I wonder if there is any equivalent command to `git ls-files` in python packaging system. If such a command exists, that would be a blessing for me to easily rectify the issue I am having with my package.

If not a command, could I in any way list all the files included in my python package, based on the conditions in the `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in`?

Comment: If you mean the distribution package archive — it depends on the archive type. A wheel (`.whl` extension) or an sdist with `.zip` extension are zip archives so use `unzip -l dist`. For an sdist with `.tar.gz` extension use `tar -tavf dist` or `tar -tzvf dist`.

Comment: To list installed files — see the file `site-packages/<package>-<version>.dist-info/RECORD`

Comment: I just meant to list all the files included in the package even before creating the whl or sdist. I suspect many big data files are unfortunately included in my package, so I would not want make their copy by creating whl or sdist. I would like to simply get a list and know which files are included upfront before I go on to create the package. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Otherwise, for small files sizes creating dist as you mentioned would have worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "*…list all the files included in the package even before creating the whl or sdist.*" Try `python setup.py bdist -n`

Comment: Well, that worked. That's great! thank you @phd! Would you like to write it as an answer? As a suggestion, you may clone this example python package https://github.com/mtchavez/python-package-boilerplate and demonstrate what  `python setup.py bdist -n` outputs.

Comment: Done. But nothing is installed for the package because you have `py_modules=['packagename'],` and don't have `packagename.py`; `py_modules` are for top-level Python **modules**. Instead you have a directory `packagename/` with `__init__.py` i.e. an importable **package**; it must be declared as `packages=['packagename'],` Please fix your `setup.py` and I'll fix my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the distribution package archive — it depends on the archive type. A wheel (`.whl` extension) or an sdist with `.zip` extension are zip archives so use `unzip -l dist-file.zip`. For an sdist with `.tar.gz` extension use `tar -tavf dist-file.tgz` or `tar -tzvf dist-file.tar.gz` (option `-a` to auto-recognize archive type, `-z` to force `gzip` compression).

To list installed files — see the file `site-packages/<package>-<version>.dist-info/RECORD`. To find out where `site-packages` is run `pip show package-name | grep -F Location:`

To list all the files included in the package even before creating the `whl` or sdist run python `setup.py bdist --dry-run`. The command lists files that will be packaged without creating a real package. For example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mtchavez/python-package-boilerplate.git
Cloning into 'python-package-boilerplate'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 116, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 116 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 112
Receiving objects: 100% (116/116), 14.03 KiB | 388.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (41/41), done.

$ cd python-package-boilerplate/

$ python setup.py bdist -n
running bdist
running bdist_dumb
running build
running build_py
file packagename.py (for module packagename) not found
file packagename.py (for module packagename) not found
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb
running install
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

running install_egg_info
running egg_info
creating py_boilerplate.egg-info
writing py_boilerplate.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to py_boilerplate.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to py_boilerplate.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'py_boilerplate.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
file packagename.py (for module packagename) not found
reading manifest file 'py_boilerplate.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'py_boilerplate.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying py_boilerplate.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/home/phd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_boilerplate-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating /home/phd/tmp/python-package-boilerplate/dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb' (and everything under it)
```

PS. All commands are for Unix/Linux command line.